# line break with span tag in css

Tags: css

```
<span class="brandname"><p class="Hfirst">Kra
<span   class="Hsecond">fterrz</span></p></span>
<p>Text</p>
```

Text appears in next line after Krafterrz.I need to remove this line break.

As far as I have read, span is an inline element. Then why do I get this line break?

CSS looks like this:

```
.Hfirst{

      color: #002060;
    }

     .Hsecond{
       color: #000000;
    }


    .brandname {
      font-family: 'Edwardian Script';
      font-size: 48px;
    }
    .brandname :first-letter {
     font-size: 72px;

}
```

How do I fix this?I want Text to be inline with Krafterrz.

Edit: I doubt it is being overridden by some other CSS class so here is what I have so far:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu-wrapper">
    <div id = "Logo" >
        <img src="images/Logo.png" ></img>
    </div>
        <div id="menu" class="container">

            <ul>
                <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#">Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="banner">
    </div>
    <div id="page" class="container">
        <div id="content">
           <span class="brandname"><p class="Hfirst">Kra<span class="Hsecond">fterrz</span></p></span>





    <div class="title">
            <span class="byline">Who are we</span> </div>
        <span class="brandname"><p class="Hfirst">Kra<span class="Hsecond">fterrz</span> 


           </p></span>
          <p>Text </p>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #16a085;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #363636;
}


h1, h2, h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

p, ol, ul {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

p {
    line-height: 190%;
}

strong {
}

a {
    color: #171717;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a img {
    border: none;
}

    .image
    {
        display: inline-block;
    }

        .image img
        {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
        }

    .image-full
    {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 0 2em 0;
    }

    .image-left
    {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 2em 2em 0;
    }

    .image-centered
    {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 0 2em 0;
    }

        .image-centered img
        {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: auto;
        }

hr {
    display: none;
}


/*********************************************************************************/
/* List Styles                                                                   */
/*********************************************************************************/

    ul.style1
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    ul.style1 li
    {
        border-top: solid 1px #E5E5E5;
        padding: 0.80em 0;
    }

    ul.style1 li:first-child
    {
        border-top: 0;
        padding-top: 0;
    }

    ul.style2
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    ul.style2 li
    {
        border-top: solid 1px #E5E5E5;
        padding: 0.80em 0;
    }

    ul.style2 li:first-child
    {
        border-top: 0;
        padding-top: 0;
    }

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Social Icon Styles                                                            */
/*********************************************************************************/

    ul.contact
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1.5em 0em 2.5em 0em;
        list-style: none;
    }

    ul.contact li
    {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0em 0.30em;
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    ul.contact li span
    {
        display: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    ul.contact li a
    {
        color: #FFF;
    }

    ul.contact li a:before
    {
        display: inline-block;
        background: #3f3f3f;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    ul.contact li a.icon-twitter:before { background: #2DAAE4; }
    ul.contact li a.icon-facebook:before { background: #39599F; }
    ul.contact li a.icon-dribbble:before { background: #C4376B; }
    ul.contact li a.icon-tumblr:before { background: #31516A; }
    ul.contact li a.icon-rss:before { background: #F2600B; }


/*********************************************************************************/
/* Heading Titles                                                                */
/*********************************************************************************/

    .title
    {
        margin-bottom: 2em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .title h2
    {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 2em;
        color: #16a085;
    }

    .title .byline
    {
        letter-spacing: 0.15em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 0.90em;
        color: #6F6F6F;
    }

/** WRAPPER */

#wrapper {
    background: #FFFFFF url(images/bg01.png) repeat;
}

#footer-wrapper
{
    background: #0F0F0F;
}

.container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}


/*********************************************************************************/
/* Wrappers                                                                      */
/*********************************************************************************/

#header-wrapper
{
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(images/bg01.png) repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    padding: 6em 0em 2em 0em;
    background: #333333;
}


/*********************************************************************************/
/* Header                                                                        */
/*********************************************************************************/

    #header 
    {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
    }

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Logo                                                                          */
/*********************************************************************************/

/*#logo 
    {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 2em 0em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    #logo h1
    {
        letter-spacing: 0.10em;
        font-size: 3em;
    }

    #logo p 
    {
        letter-spacing: 0.10em;
        color: #FFF;
    }

    #logo a 
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #FFF;
    }*/

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Banner                                                                        */
/*********************************************************************************/

    #banner 
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 300px;
        position: relative;
        background: url(images/pic02.png) no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    #banner .image
    {
    }
    #banner p{
    position: absolute; 
    top:30%;
    left: 40%;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 5px; 
    margin: 5px;
    font-family: 'Edwardian Script';
    font-weight: 590;

    }

    .Hfirst{

      color: #002060;
    }

     .Hsecond{
       color: #000000;
    }


    .brandname {
      font-family: 'Edwardian Script';
      font-size: 48px;
    }
    .brandname :first-letter {
     font-size: 72px;

}


/** MENU */

#menu-wrapper
{
    background: #16a085;
    overflow:auto;
}

#menu {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#menu a {
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 0px 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 0.80em;
    line-height: 100px;
    border: none;
    color: #FFF;
}

#menu a:hover, #menu .current_page_item a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu .current_page_item a {
    background: #1abc9c;
}

#Logo img{
width:100px;
height:90px;
float: left;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left:5px;
background: transparent;
z-index:-1;
opacity: 0.6;
}

/** PAGE */

#page
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 6em 0em 5em 0em;
}

/** CONTENT */

#content
{
    float: left;
    width: 790px;
}

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Sidebar                                                                       */
/*********************************************************************************/

    #sidebar
    {
        float: right;
        width: 345px;
    }

    #sidebar .title h2
    {
        font-size: 1.6em;
    }

    #sidebar .box1
    {
        margin-bottom: 3em;
    }


/*********************************************************************************/
/* Copyright                                                                     */
/*********************************************************************************/

    #copyright
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 5em 0em;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #copyright p
    {
        letter-spacing: 0.20em;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 0.80em;
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    }

    #copyright a
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
    }

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Welcome                                                                       */
/*********************************************************************************/

    #welcome
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 5em 0em;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #welcome h2
    {
        letter-spacing: 0.20em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 2.6em;
    }

    #welcome p
    {
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }

    #welcome .byline
    {
        display: block;
        padding: 0em 0em 1.5em 0em;
        letter-spacing: 0.15em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        color: #6F6F6F;
    }

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Portfolio                                                                     */
/*********************************************************************************/

    #portfolio-wrapper
    {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.04);
        padding: 6em 0em;
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
    }

    #portfolio
    {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #portfolio .title h2
    {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        color: #FFF;
    }

    #portfolio .byline
    {
        font-size: 1em;
        color: #EEA7C1;
    }

    #column1,
    #column2,
    #column3,
    #column4
    {
        width: 282px;
    }

    #column1,
    #column2
    {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 24px;
    }

    #column3
    {
        float: left;
    }

    #column4
    {
        float: right;
    }

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Button Style                                                                  */
/*********************************************************************************/

    .button
    {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 1.5em;
        padding: 1.50em 3em 1.50em 3em;
        background: #16a085;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 0.90em;
        color: #FFF;
    }

        .button:before
        {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            line-height: 40px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #FFF;
        }

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Footer                                                                        */
/*********************************************************************************/

    #footer-wrapper
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 5em 0em;
        background: #1E1B1A;
    }

    #footer
    {
        color: #ADADAD;
    }

    #footer .title h2
    {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        color: #FFF;
    }

    #footer .title
    {
        border-color: #2D2926 !important;
    }

    #footer .style1 li
    {
        border-color: #2D2926 !important;
    }

    #footer .style1 a
    {
        font-size:1em;
        color: #B1B1B1;
    }

    #box1
    {
        float: left;
        width: 354px;
        margin-right: 24px;
        padding-right: 30px;
    }

    #box2
    {
        float: left;
        width: 354px;
        margin-left: 24px;
        padding-right: 30px;
    }

    #box3
    {
        float: right;
        width: 344px;
        padding-left: 40px;
    }
```

Comment: replace every `<p>` with `<span>` and it will work as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is basic behavior of p tag. If you really want to overwrite it you can do it this way:

```
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Did not change the way it is rendered

Comment: In your example the first text (who we are) stays lower because of div tag. Div and p tags align your elements into blocks. If you want to keep strings on the line use span instead of div. If you want to check how this works you can use p, div {display: inline-block;} which will do what you want but (of corse) mess your design.